# php upload/download move uploaded file

Tags: php, mysql, upload, download

Having some issues with my upload/download process. My file is inserted to mysql as BLOB, but when downloaded it grabs the html markup of the calling php page.  Do I need to move uploaded file to a temporary directory before inserting to the database?

EDIT: current upload.php file.  Still getting html content and not the actual file itself, it is still named correctly.

```
           <?php
                    // Make sure an ID was passed DOWNLOAD HANDLER *******
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']); var_dump($id);


    require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db



        // Fetch the file information
        $downloadq = "
            SELECT `file_type`, `size`, `title`, 'content', 'upload_id'
            FROM `upload`
            WHERE `upload_id` =".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $downloadq); // Run the query


        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                //var_dump($row);

                // Print headers
                header("Content-Type: application/msword");
                header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
               header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['title']);
               header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");


                // Print data
                echo (stripslashes($row['content']));


            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No such ID.';
            }

            // Free the mysqli resources
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbc->error}</pre>";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);
}
                ?>
```

Comment: please post the download code. If you are using headers you are not supposed to have any text in the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "it grabs the html markup of the calling php page?" - Can you upload the file that it creates?

Comment: It's hard to explain.  Say I'm on newpub_profile.php - the page where the table and download links are displayed.  I click "download", a file is downloaded that has the correct title, however, when I open the file I find that the contents of the file is the html of newpub_profile.php.  So I can see my header, sidebars, footer, images.

Comment: You should set your page content type to that file specific type. This might be a good source: http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download. But I'm not sure because I'd never any project using database BLOB format to recover my files.

Answer (score 0):

You can pls try this.
After the following line

```
echo (stripslashes($row['content']));
```

write one more line

```
exit;
```

Maybe this will  help you.

Comment: tried it. still incorrect file contents.  I have began work on using the files system: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646613/cant-get-some-session-variables-across-pages

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (
    `id`        Int Unsigned Not Null Auto_Increment,
    `name`      VarChar(255) Not Null Default 'Untitled.txt',
    `mime`      VarChar(50) Not Null Default 'text/plain',
    `size`      BigInt Unsigned Not Null Default 0,
    `data`      MediumBlob Not Null,
    `created`   DateTime Not Null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```