# can't get SOME session variables across pages

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Trying to add some extra elements to my session variables for filesystem directory work, and I noticed that I can't add some.  Here's what I have:

```
    <?php
#login.php

// This page processes the login form submission.

// Upon successful login, the user is redirected.

// Two included files are necessary.

// Check if the form has been submitted:

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{

    // For processing the login:

    require_once ('login_functions.php');

    // Need the database connection:

    require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php');

    // Check the login:

    list ($check, $data) = check_login($dbc, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

    if ($check) //OK!
    {
        // set the session data:

      session_start();

      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['user_id'];

      $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];

      $_SESSION['company_name'] = $data['company_name'];

      $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];


      // Store the HTTP_USER_AGENT:

      $_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        //Redirect:

        $url = absolute_url ('loggedin.php');

        header("Location: $url");

        exit(); // Quit the script.

    }
    else // Unsuccessful!
    {

       // Assign $data to $errors for error reporting
        // in the login_functions.php file.

        $errors = $data;

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection


} //End of the main submit conditional

//Create the page:

include('login_page_inc.php');



?>
```

here are the login functions:

```
    <?php #login_functions.php

//This page defines two functions used by the login/logout process.

/*This function determines and returns an absolute URL.
 * It takes one argument: the page that concludes the URL.
 * The argument defaults to index.php
 */

function absolute_url ($page = 'about.php')
{
    //Start defining the URL...
    //URL is http:// plus the host name plus the current directory:

    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // Remove any trailing slashes:

    $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');

    // Add the page:
    $url .= '/' . $page;

    // Return the URL:

    return $url;

}//End of absolute_url() function.

/*This function validates the form data (email address and password).
 * If both are present, the database is queried.
 * The function requires a database connection
 * The function returns an array of information, including:
 *  - a TRUE/FALSE variable indicating success
 * - an array of either errors or the database result
 */

function check_login($dbc, $email = '', $pass = '')
{
    $errors = array(); // Initialize error array.

    // Validate the email address:

    if (empty($email))
    {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
    }
    else
    {
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));
    }

    // Validate the password:

    if (empty($pass))
    {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
    }
    else
    {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pass));
    }

    if(empty($errors)) //If everything's OK.
    {
        // Retrieve the user_id and first_name for that email/password combo

        $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, email FROM
            user WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";

        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

        //Check the result:

        if (mysqli_num_rows($r)==1)
        {
            //Fetch the record:

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            // Return true and the record:

            return array (true, $row);


        }
        else //Not a match for writer, check the publisher table
        {
            $q = "SELECT pub_id, company_name, cemail FROM
                pub WHERE cemail='$e' AND password=SHA1('$p')";

            $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($r)==1)
         {
            //Fetch the record:

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            // Return true and the record:

            return array (true, $row);

        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p>Invalid Credentials</p>';

         }
        }

    } // End of empty($errors) IF.

    // Return false and the errors:

    return array(false, $errors);

} // End of check_login() function.


?>
```

Note: $_SESSION['first_name'] and $_SESSION['company_name'] have always worked correctly, however adding email and user_id is not working.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to log what you have in $data, maybe there is no values in $data['user_id'] and $data['email']

Comment: under closer inspection, user_id is working, leaving email that's broke.

Comment: Add this code and see if any value appears echo($data['user_id']);  echo($data['email']);

Comment: I try to echo this on the welcome screen alongside the user's first name, I cant get a value to echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

email and user_id will never work for the publisher: as the login function returns "pub_id" and "cemail". To fix this, you could change the SQL to:

```
        $q = "SELECT pub_id as user_id, company_name, cemail AS email FROM 
            pub WHERE cemail='$e' AND password=SHA1('$p')";
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  But why can't I get any echo output for user_id and email for a regular user login?

Comment: At a total guess, the SQL fails to match, or it matches more than one row? Make a habit of after every SQL call, check for an error in the SQL (i.e. if $r== false). But also echo out the route the system is taking and also see if num_rows = 0 or 2 from your first query.

Comment: And how many rows are returned? It could be 2 (if you have dodgy test data). It cuold be 0 (even though you think it should be 1). This means you won't get anything back. What I'm saying, it just debug that part to check what you think should be happenning is happening - you're missing off error checking such as if the SQL fails or returns more rows (=unexpected) etc

Comment: I can't get any error checking to output.  I've tried mysqli_store_result() before doing a $number = mysqli_num_rows($r); then echo it out to the greeting alongside $_SESSION['first_name'].  Can't see anything useful in view page source either.

Comment: remove the @ before the mysqli_query, vardump($r); var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($r)) etc. Just to see what happens. Then remove them if you spot anything untoward.

Comment: getting this output when I put in garbage login credentials:                object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) } int(0)

Comment: That's fine - num_rows = 0; so it's not found a row, which you expect with garbage. But I thought your problem was you're looking for valid data that isn't returning - wo what happens when you put in good credentials?

Comment: When credentials are valid I can log in and first_name is displayed at the greeting screen via session-no vardump is shown on the page or in viewsource, however, I can't get an email session to display on that page.  I'm trying to place user uploads into a folder which is named after that users email address and I can't think of a better way to direct the upload to the correct folder other than by grabbing the users session['email']